# Can Html.Display/Html.DisplayFor/Html.DisplayForModel work with a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015025/how-do-i-display-a-datatable-in-asp-net-mvc-2) question on how to display a `DataTable` in a view but was wondering if `Html.Display` or `Html.DisplayFor` could be made to work with a `DataTable`?

**NB:**

> Use of `DataTable` is required for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a DisplayTemplate by creating a partial view under my View folder in a folder called DisplayTemplates. I called the partial view Table. The model it uses is a datatable and below is the code.  In your view you can then do `@Html.DisplayForModel("Table")`

```
@using System.Data;
@model DataTable
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @{
                foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                <th>@col.ColumnName
                </th>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
            <tr>
                @{foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                  {
                    <td>@row[col]
                    </td>
                  }
                }
            </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mapped your data table into an IEnumerable of an object, I believe DisplayFor would handle this.

Comment: Yup agree but I have to use a DataTable as I don't know what the properties will be for the object.

Comment: In Typed Datasets, DataTable is already IEnumerable. In other cases you can use `mydatatable.AsEnumerable()`. An item of IEnumerable is a DataRow (or inherited in case of Typed Datasets), so it depends if DataRow is already supported by Html.Display/Html.DisplayFor, or you should implement it.

Comment: I'm wondering if a custom DisplayTemplate might work but not sure how to implement it really.