# Telerik MVC Grid : Putting a button in a column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

What im trying to do is have an edit button that instead of opening the line for editing, it forwards you to a page where you can edit. Is this possible? I tried something with the client template, but the grid render is ignoring it completely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc

w/ Model strongly typed as System.Data.DataTable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can place a component into a grid column. Heres an example of how I bound the Id column with an Action link to the edit action passing in the Id.

I've removed the other columns from the template for clarity.

```
        Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
            .Name("Items")
            .DataKeys(keys => { keys.Add(x => x.Id); })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Title("").Format(Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = "{0}" }).ToHtmlString()).Encoded(false).Width(60);
            })
            .Render();
```

Comment: Can i give the html.actionlink a css class?

Comment: Sure. It uses the normal Html helper method so: Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = "{0}", @class="mycss" }

Comment: I air coded the last comment. Updated: Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = "{0}"}, new { @class="mycss" })

Answer (score 2):

You can use Template method instead:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
      .Name("Items")
      .DataKeys(keys => { keys.Add(x => x.Id); })
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                 .Title("")
                 .Template(@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { x.id }))
                 .Width(60);
      })
)
```