# How do I get a data table from a select query done to Oracle and display it in my view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I want to be able to return a table in my oracle db and send it to be displayed in my view in my MVC structure. My code looks something like this for my model:

```
        public DataTable Show(int Poll_ID)
    {

        OleDbDataReader myOleDBDataReader = DBConn("SELECT * FROM MCQ_QUESTIONS WHERE Poll_ID = 1");

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        DataTable schemaTable = myOleDBDataReader.GetSchemaTable();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        for (int cntr = 0; cntr < schemaTable.Rows.Count; ++cntr)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = schemaTable.Rows[cntr];
            string columnName = dataRow["ColumnName"].ToString();
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, dataRow.GetType());
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        myOleDBDataReader.Close();
        myOleDbConnection.Close();
        return dataTable;
```

But its not working. Any help is appreciated guys!! Code from my Controller class is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        PollModel poll = new PollModel();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = poll.Show(1);
        //ViewData["Poll"] = poll.Show();
        ViewData["Data"] = dt;
        //ViewData["Poll"] = "Testing";
        return View(dt);
    }
```

Code in my view is as follows :

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MvcApplication3.Models" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Details
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Data"])%>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why this not works? can you post the error?

Comment: It returns an empty string in my view.

Comment: are you sure datatable is filled with data?

Comment: Any reason for using `DataSet` and `DataTable` instead of strongly typed models?

Comment: Im new to c# and MVC for that matter and googling recommended using both of those types to reference a select query done on a table

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the code that add row to dataTable. you just create the table's schema without data. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would recommend you is to use the [ODP.NET driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) to access an Oracle database instead of ODBC. The second thing I would recommend you is to use models instead of `DataSet` and `DataTables` which were used in classic `WebForms` (even if they shouldn't have) but not in ASP.NET MVC.

So once you have downloaded the proper driver from Oracle let's get to coding. Start by describing what a `Question` is. For example:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

then write a repository method which will return a list of questions:

```
public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
{
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection("put your CS string here or fetch from app.config"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MCQ_ID, MCQ_TITLE FROM MCQ_QUESTIONS WHERE Poll_ID = 1";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new Question
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MCQ_ID")),
                    Title = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("MCQ_TITLE"))
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can move on to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var questions = repository.GetQuestions().ToArray();
    return View(questions);
}
```

And finally the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
         Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Question>>" 
%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Details
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

And finally in the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Question.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication3.Models.Question>" 
%>
<tr>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %></td>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title) %></td>
</tr>
```

You may also checkout the [tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/mvc) about using Entity Framework as an ORM to avoid writing SQL queries in your code.

Comment: public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions() doesn't seem to work despite importing System.Collections, error I'm getting is as follows:
"The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments". Help!

Comment: This works great if/when a query returns one row... what would you suggest for a query that returns >1 row? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try looking here:

[Displaying standard DataTables in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2243898/735864)

this can be interesting:

```
 <% foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows) { %>
    <tr>
        <% foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray) {%>
            <td><%=cell.ToString() %></td>
        <%} %>
    </tr>
<%} %>
```

Comment: I'll try whats stated in that post.

Comment: I've to return in my prev question... are you sure datatable contains data? Have you debugged it for rows property?