# How binding random count column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding

How binding this (`dynamic`) table to `IList<IList<string>>` or another type

html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                <tr><td><input type="text" value="@i" name="column1_@(i)"/></td><td><input type="text" value="@(Guid.NewGuid())" name="column2_@(i)"/></td></tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value ="send"/>
}
```

I need get columns and rows

**Update:**

maybe I can take String[][]

Comment: You mean something like this? http://blog.gfader.com/2010/05/aspnet-mvc-model-binding-to-list-or-how.html

Comment: partially, but I need dynamic row and dynamic column

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Accepting a `FormCollection` in the `POST` action has a result set with 20 items (one for each input).

Comment: You can pass dataTable to view(if I undestood correct) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc

Comment: @AliRıza Adıyahşi, yes but I need and submit table

Comment: @Forty-Two, yes. but I need take 10 row of 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use a `Dictionary<string, string>`, but that's not indexable, so you'd have to write a custom model binder.  Not that hard, but still.  Then I thought about using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, but `KeyValuePair`s have private setters, so, again, you'd need a custom binder. 
So I think the best way is:

Create a custom type

```
public class MyItems
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, add a list of this type as a property to your view model

```
public List<MyItems> MyItems  { get; set; }
```

And, after populating the list and strongly typing your view, of course, you can render your table using the built in html helpers to ensure model binding won't have any hiccups

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyItems.Count( ); i++ )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.MyItems[i].Key )</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.MyItems[i].Value)</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Then catch the model in the controller and access you data

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Model viewModel)
        {
            foreach (var item in viewModel.MyItems)
            {
                string columnOneValue = viewModel.MyItems[0].Key;
                string columnTwoValue = viewModel.MyItems[0].Value; 
            }
```

Comment: I dont have model, this example static I need dynamic model