# How to show Xml Xdocument in table MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to show any xml in table in my mvc app like in photo

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JoyO0mTmhnNWplMlR6ME5PeW8/edit?usp=sharing

this is my code but it work only for one parent element in xml

```
enter code here String f1 = Session["doc2"].ToString();
        Value model2 = new Value();


        HttpPostedFileBase file2 = TempData["doc3"] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        var fileex = Path.GetExtension(file2.FileName);
        string xmlstr = ".xml"; 
        string strall = "";

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(f1);
             var abc = xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                                               .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();
            ViewBag.MyListabc = abc;
            var abcd = xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                                                   .Select(x => x.Value).Distinct();
            ViewBag.MyListabcd = abcd;


        model2 = new Value()
        {

            file1 = abc

        };


        //ViewBag.MyList = listelem;
        return View(model2);


    }
```

And this is my view

```
enter code here<table style="font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#333333;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #666666;
border-collapse: collapse;">
```

`@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyListabc)
    {`

```
                   <th style="border: 1px solid; width:80px">   @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => item) </th>

}</tr>
```

`@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyListabcd)
    {
             <td style="border: 1px solid; width:80px"> 
  @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => item) </td>`

```
}</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse your xml table to a DataTable object and then render your DataTable in your view. Some links for inspiration.

- [Displaying standard DataTables in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/11/19/asp-net-mvc-simple-view-to-display-contents-of-datatable.aspx