# How to bind c# variable to HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a DataTable from a SQL query in the the controller.

How do I "connect" '#example' with 'categories'?

> EDIT1: After suggestion to use jQuery.DataTables

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>Employee Index Page</h1>
        <table id="example">

</div>
</body>
</html>

@{ var categories = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewData["MyData"]; }

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

> ORIGINAL

```
I want to assign this to a gridview. The Code from the View is below but GridView1 needs to be defined somehow.

In the c# categories has the right contents, but GridView1 get the error "does not exist in the current context".

How and where do I fix that?

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Employee Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <h1>Employee Index Page</h1>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                          runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetData() %>' AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            </asp:GridView>
            @{ 
                var categories = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewData["MyData"];
                GridView1.DataSource = categories;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using asp:gridview in MVC?

Comment: Web search suggested it was a simple way to display a DataTable. I am open to alternatives!

Comment: Personally, I would look at using datatables (or similar) with MVC http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: You can't mix ASP controls and MVC I am pretty sure (honestly I have never thought to try...)

Comment: You can just do a normal HTML `<table>` and for-loop over all the headers, columns, rows, etc...

Comment: @MichaelCoxon So JQuery.DataTables is a good solution?

Comment: I am using : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/creating-simple-grid-in-mvc-using-grid-mvc/

Comment: jQuery DataTables is just a JS plugin for formatting an already built HTML `<table>` it adds client side filtering, paging and junk. You still need to write out all the HTML manually.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc Keep in mind that this is just a quick fix for the way you have already set up your model. But honestly, I would seriously recommend that you change your model to be an `IEnumerable<MyDataItem>` since it is so much easier to read and seperates the view model from the domain model - which is typically what you want to do in MVC.

Comment: @ChrisBint I have made changes to the question - how do I connect jquery.datatable with my datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend to you not to put everyrthing in one view, Create View for Grid take `@model List<YourClass>` and View for your Layout.

For Display GridView in MVC, There are many options (Free and not-free)

- https://www.datatables.net/
- https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid
- https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/

DataTable Example

```
your Html for example
---------------------
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model)
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Position</td>
            </tr>
         <tbody>
    </table>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
 <script> 
      $(document).ready(function () { 
         $('#example').DataTable(); 
       }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: Ahmed, I have made changes to the question - how do I connect jquery.datatable with my datatable?

Comment: you need to unserstand more about MVC first and javascript

Comment: this is an opensource project I created before using MVC, javscript, Ajax ,, i think it will help 
https://github.com/AhmedRagheb/Movies-Search

Comment: @ManInMoon I Edit my answer with example to how use DataTable

Comment: Ahmed, thank you for code above. I am confused - why do you need to loop through and create rows when using JQuery.Datatable? I might as well just write the HTML? I thought point of Jquery was to make it simpler?

Comment: Jquery DataTable helper library convert your table to GridView with some functionality like search, sort ... my example I fill table using MVC razor but you can fill it using Ajax or anything else .. you got it !! :)

Comment: Ahmed, I have that all working EXCEPT the Javascript - where do I put that? Currently it is under my HTML body. I don't think it gets called

Comment: Did you add the script file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126909/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-ahmed-ragheb).

Comment: @ManInMoon If this answer your question, solved your problem and you satisifed with answer, could you mark it as solved to help other who search

Comment: For others reading this - a key point is to remove layout=null in the view.