# Binding data directly from model of asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I developed a textbox control which shows rounded off data on `blur` and actual data on `focus`. currently this is being done using JS and value change has no relation with ASP.NET model.

Is it possible to add two properties to model and bind them to these events? ie, If I have A & B, on `blur` A should be bound and on `focus` B should be bound. And each time when user modifies B, the changed value should be reflected in A (after rounding off).

I checked many websites, but I couldn't understand any of it. Few of them are,

- [Model Binding in ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding)
- [Displaying standard DataTables in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc)
- [Remote Validation for LIST of MODELs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you're after here is having both the rounded and actual data on post. If so, there's a better way than actually posting both. Just add a property to your view model that returns the rounded data:

```
public decimal Data { get; set; }

public int RoundedData
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Data, 0)); }
}
```

Comment: But if user edits that, then he will see actual value on blur, not rounded one. right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with what's going on client-side. Presumably from your question, you already have that piece covered.

Comment: Actually, I'm searching for a way to avoid using any client side scripting. Is that possible?

Comment: No. Not if you want the user to have immediate feedback (focus/blur). That happens client-side and must be handled client-side.

Comment: Thanks. That what I wanted to know. :) Please update the answer. I'll mark it.