# ViewData doesn't show any data when called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So i tried to make tables on controller here's the code i was typing

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
        Table.Columns.Add("Nama", typeof(string));
        Table.Columns.Add("Nama2", typeof(string));

        Table.Rows.Add("Manama", "Jeff");
        Table.Rows.Add("Damn", "Daniel");

        ViewData["Test"] = Table;



@ViewData["Test"] // when i type this it doesnt show anything on new page when i run it
```

Comment: Note that your `ViewData` contains `DataTable`, and using `@ViewData["Test"]` will return fully-qualified name e.g. `System.Data.DataTable` instead of its content (because `ToString()` is implicitly called). You need to iterate the `DataTable` as `IEnumerable<string>` to get its results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is `@ViewData["Test"]` implicitly calls `ToString()` to the `DataTable` object, which will return fully-qualified name of `System.Data.DataTable` instead of its contents (rows & columns). If you want to create a table from it, you should create HTML `<table>` structure like this:

```
@using System.Data
@{
    var table = ViewData["Test"] as DataTable;
}

<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
           {
               <th>@col.Caption</th>
           }
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or better passing `DataTable` directly to model:

**Controller Action**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Nama", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Nama2", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("Manama", "Jeff");
table.Rows.Add("Damn", "Daniel");

return View(table);
```

**View**

```
@using System.Data

<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
           {
               <th>@col.Caption</th>
           }
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhM3A1) contains live example how you should create the table inside view page.

Related issue:

[Displaying standard DataTables in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243898/displaying-standard-datatables-in-mvc)